# Loads wrong partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views, renderpartial

I how two controllers, `Project` and `SubProject` and a table of `Reports` which has a column which is left empty if is populated from `Project` and adds the `SubProject_id` if is populated from `SubProject`.

Project controller show action

```
@keywords = @project.keywords
```

SubProject controller show action

```
@reports = @project.keywords
```

In the project#show I render the `@keywords` and in the `_keyword.html.erb` partial I have

```
 <tr>
  <td><%=keyword.id%></td> 
  <td><%=keyword.name%></td>
  <td>
  <%=keyword.reports.where(subproject_id: nil).find_each do |keyword_r|%>
    [<%=keyword_r.possition%>]
  <%end%>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In my `subproject#show` I render `@reports`, and in the `_report.html.erb` partial I have

```
 <%report.find_each do |keyword_r|%>
  <tr><td> <%=keyword_r.name%></td>
    <td>
      <%keyword_r.reports.where(subproject_id: !nil).each do |kr|%>
        [<%=kr.possition%>]
      <%end%>
    </td>
  </tr>
<%end%>
```

The problem is that, if I do `<%=render @reports%>` it's going to render `@keywords`.
But when I do `<%= render partial: "report", locals: {report: @reports}%>`, is going to render the correct partial.
Why can't I use <%= render @reports%>?
Or what I am doing wrong and why in the reports partial I need two loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= render @reports %>
```

Rails uses the class of the objects to determine which partial to use, not the name of the collection variable. The collection `@reports` contains `Keyword` objects, so the `_keyword.html.erb` partial is used, unless you specifiy otherwise.

See 3.4.5 in [Rails rendering guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), you can even have objects of different classes, each object will be rendered with the partial matching its class.